# Can a border grow in?

Tags: css

The general problem I am trying to solve is the alignment of stacked boxes (`<div>`) when some of them have a different border width.

Consider the two boxes below

```css
.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.thick {
  border-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box thick"></div>
```

They are both of the same sizes, but the border is growing out of the box, breaking their alignment.

I can compensate for this with some tricks (shifting the box, having a thick transparent border, ...) but I would ideally like to keep the total size fixed, and grow the border "in".

Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah, it's called `box-sizing` and you need a value of `border-box`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: As Roberto said. I use to have `*{box-sizing:border-box}` as the first line in my css sheets

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković: Thanks! Would you mind turning this into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez `*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I do not understand what you mean, but if I do, you could maybe accomplish what you want with the "box-shadow" property. Like this:

```css
.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.thick {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 29px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box thick"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of accomplishing this by using the `outline` and `outline-offset` rule as shown in the example below.

```css
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.thick {
   outline: 10px solid red;
   outline-offset: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box thick"></div>
```

**EDIT**
I also highly suggest you always use the `border-box` as shown in the snippet. This [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?retiredLocale=nl) about box-sizing will explain it more in detail.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.thick {
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box thick"></div>
```

Comment: For the boxes to align perfectly, shouldn't the first box also have `box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: Your point was correct thank you.